# Custom cost function for tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, neural-network

Is there any way I can have this custom cost for my op in Tensorflow?

```
n_step =5
for i in range(0,int(train_size/n_step)):
    W=[0]
    I=[0]
    for j in range(n_step):
        W.append(max(W[j]+train_y[i*n_step+j]-yhat[i*n_step+j],0))
        I.append(max(-W[j]-train_y[i*n_step+j]+yhat[i*n_step+j],0))

    loss += 2*np.sum(W)+1*np.sum(I)
```

where `yhat` is the output of a fully connected network and `W`, `I` are auxiliaries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just have to add your `loss` to the collection of losses with [tf.losses.add_loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/add_loss).

In order for you to be able to do that, you have to express your loss function in terms of tensors and tensor operations, however. Numpy operations as in your code will not do.

Comment: thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I am not worried about adding my loss to the loss collection. But the problem is how to have both input data (in here train_y) and tesnor objects (yhat) in the objective. I think we can use tf.convert_to_tensor for W and I and convert them to tensors and use tf.reduce_sum to find the total loss per epoch.

Comment: Whatever you add to the loss collection will be part of the training and optimized. I thought that was your objective, to make sure your network is trained to minimize your special loss too.